# Insert variable into Wordpress page title for individual page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a photo gallery page that is using a single page in Wordpress.

The gallery display is dynamic, and relies on a URL parameter. The parameter itself is an integer of the relating wordpress page ID. (as that's the page it's about).

Here is an example of a gallery URL:

http://www.bellavou.co.uk/gallery/?pid=238

For SEO purposes, I'm trying to get away from every possible Gallery URL combination to have the page title 'Gallery', as is set in the Wordpress page settings.

I've been trying this, which has been mentioned a few times:

```
function assignPageTitle(){
  return "Title goes here";
}
add_filter('wp_title', 'assignPageTitle');
```

But as I'm also using Yoast SEO plugin, I think this is over-writing it (even though I uncheck 'Force title rewrite', and keep the page title field blank). Not sure why the above function doesn't seem to work.

Within the gallery page, I'm able to show the `h1` title properly, passing PHP Variables into the code, but I want to do the same to the page title, but in a way that can be done directly on the page template.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it that whenever I post a question, I seem to find the answer very soon afterwards?

I read a post saying that it helps to put a wp_title function before the wp_header call, which is what I tried, and that seems to work fine.

I can edit the page title just for an individual page using the PHP page template, and using this:

```
$procedure = isset($_GET['pid']) ? $_GET['pid'] : '';
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_title_gallery', 100 );
function wp_title_gallery($title) {
    global $procedure;
    if(!$procedure) {
        $title = the_title();
    } else {
        $title = the_title(get_the_title($procedure).'&nbsp');
    }
    return $title;
}
get_header();
```

`$procedure` gets the URL parameter, and then the function takes that ID, and gets the associated page from it, and then prints the title of the page, into the page title hook. Lastly, the WP header is called.

(Just incase anyone comes here looking for a solution)